# Xamarin Forms Toolbaritems are not show

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.forms, appcompatactivity, toolbaritems

I'm trying to create toolbaritems in my root page.
Toolbaritems arent show only in startup page, if i navigate to new page, they are there.

Fragment xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:CoolContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FBAndroid"      
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             EnableBackButtonOverride="False"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Title="Logowanie"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource Key=PageWithGradient}"
             x:Class="FBAndroid.Pages.LoginPage">


<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="Logowanie" FontSize="24" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbi_options" Text="Ustawienia"    Priority="0" Order="Default" Clicked="Tbi_options_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbi_exit"  Text="Zakończ"  Priority="1" Order="Default" Clicked="tbi_cofnij_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

in App()

```
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#AD2728"),
                BarTextColor = Color.Black
            };
```

And MainActivity fragment because if i remove `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar)` than will show toolbaritems on my root page.

```
namespace FBAndroid.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "FBAndroid", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            CheckAppPermissions();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }
        }
```

How make that the SetSupportActionBar (i used that for override navigation back button. Solution from [theconfuzedsourcecode](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/comment-page-1/#comment-1167)) not necessary to remove and toolbar items has been show.

Comment: Hi,  i dont have any experience with coolcontentpage but in classic content page i always specify  NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True" and i have no issues.. And just thinking you have coolcontentpage but adding toolbar to ContentPage

Comment: Thanks for response. I put ```NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);``` before InitializeComponent but this does't helped

Comment: ok, sorry, i am not that experienced :) . Hope you find solution soon

Comment: Put `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);` after the line `InitializeComponent ` . @TomR

Comment: [sample](https://easyupload.io/bdrb22) is done. I prepared sample for testing. When you run app, try navigate from LoginPage(root) to MainPage and come back than tbi will display. @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: So you want the ToolBarItems on LoginPage will never been display ?

Comment: No, i want see ToolBarItems at startup app in LoginPage

Comment: Remove `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in Android

Comment: I need this method for override navigation bar back button.

Comment: You can override navigation bar back button in forms project. Customize the navigationbar.